# Nest/ElasticSearch Sorting by _uid

Tags: c#, sorting, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to pull back records based on a query and sort them using the `_uid` field. In my case the `_uid` is the Type followed by # followed by the id that I set. My index is full of files of code and an example of the `_uid` would be `myType#MyDocuments/File.txt`

So I'm doing a sort on `_uid` ascending. It Mostly works, it sorts the types into order but within the types it only sorts correctly with the upper most directory.

So I'll see something like

```
Accounting/AP_ABC.asp
Accounting/AR_ABC.asp
Accounting/Account.asp
```

Which isn't right because Account should come before AP and AR.

Is there a way to make sure this would sort correctly?

**EDIT**
Adding a mapping from my index

```
"dotnet":{"properties":{"fileContents":{"type":"string"},"filePath":{"type":"string"},"lastUpdate":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"type":{"type":"string"}}}
```

Comment: '_uid' field is analyzed or not_analtzed?

Comment: `_uid` is generated by elastic search not something I set. Can I change it to be not_analyzed?

Comment: Type localhost:9200/indexname/_mapping into your browser and show what have you got.

Comment: Edited the main post

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new not_analyzed field like sortid which will hold not analyzed values of your ids(Accounting/Account.asp). [This](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/multi-fields.html) article will explain in details why would you like to do this.

**UPDATE**:

Try to apply [case-insensitive sorting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-collations.html#case-insensitive-sorting). 
Later on I'll update my answer with an working example.

**UPDATE2**

1. The easiest way to achievie what you are trying do is to create
   index with following mapping:

   ```
   client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor
       .Index(indexName)
       .AddMapping<Document>(m => m
           .Properties(p => p
               .String(s => s.Name(n => n.Id).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)))));

   class Document
   {
       public string Id { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Index some documents with lowercase id values:

   ```
   client.Index(new Document {Id = "Accounting/AP_ABC.asp".ToLower()});
   client.Index(new Document {Id = "Accounting/AR_ABC.asp".ToLower()});
   client.Index(new Document {Id = "Accounting/Account.asp".ToLower()});
   ```

   Then for this sorting

   ```
   var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
       .Sort(sort => sort
           .OnField(f => f.Id).Ascending()));
   ```

   we will get

   ```
   {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
         "total": 5,
         "successful": 5,
         "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
         "total": 3,
         "max_score": null,
         "hits": [
            {
               "_index": "indexname",
               "_type": "document",
               "_id": "accounting/account.asp",
               "_score": null,
               "_source": {
                  "id": "accounting/account.asp"
               },
               "sort": [
                  "accounting/account.asp"
               ]
            },
            {
               "_index": "indexname",
               "_type": "document",
               "_id": "accounting/ap_abc.asp",
               "_score": null,
               "_source": {
                  "id": "accounting/ap_abc.asp"
               },
               "sort": [
                  "accounting/ap_abc.asp"
               ]
            },
            {
               "_index": "indexname",
               "_type": "document",
               "_id": "accounting/ar_abc.asp",
               "_score": null,
               "_source": {
                  "id": "accounting/ar_abc.asp"
               },
               "sort": [
                  "accounting/ar_abc.asp"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
   ```
2. But if you really care about Ids as you provided(e.g
   Accounting/AP_ABC.asp) you can use mentioned earlier
   [Case-Insensitive Sorting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-collations.html#case-insensitive-sorting).

   To apply this solution with NEST:

   Create mapping as below

   ```
   client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor
       .Index(indexName)
       .Analysis(analysisDescriptor => analysisDescriptor
           .Analyzers(a => a
               .Add("case_insensitive_sort", new CustomAnalyzer
               {
                   Tokenizer = "keyword",
                   Filter = new List<string> {"lowercase"}
               })))
       .AddMapping<Document>(m => m
           .Properties(p => p
               .String(s => s
                   .Name(n => n.Id)
                   .Analyzer("case_insensitive_sort")))));
   ```

   Index documents:

   ```
   client.Index(new Document {Id = "Accounting/AP_ABC.asp"});
   client.Index(new Document {Id = "Accounting/AR_ABC.asp"});
   client.Index(new Document {Id = "Accounting/Account.asp"});
   ```

   And for sorting we will sort we will get following result

   ```
   {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
         "total": 5,
         "successful": 5,
         "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
         "total": 3,
         "max_score": null,
         "hits": [
            {
               "_index": "indexname",
               "_type": "document",
               "_id": "Accounting/Account.asp",
               "_score": null,
               "_source": {
                  "id": "Accounting/Account.asp"
               },
               "sort": [
                  "accounting/account.asp"
               ]
            },
            {
               "_index": "indexname",
               "_type": "document",
               "_id": "Accounting/AP_ABC.asp",
               "_score": null,
               "_source": {
                  "id": "Accounting/AP_ABC.asp"
               },
               "sort": [
                  "accounting/ap_abc.asp"
               ]
            },
            {
               "_index": "indexname",
               "_type": "document",
               "_id": "Accounting/AR_ABC.asp",
               "_score": null,
               "_source": {
                  "id": "Accounting/AR_ABC.asp"
               },
               "sort": [
                  "accounting/ar_abc.asp"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
   ```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I created a not_analyzed field called "sortByField" with type "string" and it still sorts the same way as i mentioned in the original post

Comment: Did you reindexed your data?

Comment: Yes i deleted everything, created new index and mappings with that field and it still sorts exactly the same...i now have this in my mapping: "sortByField": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }